# Use of If/Else Statement in Java considering memory IO

Tags: java, if-statement, memory-management

I know this might be stupid question, but i am wondering when is the right time to use `if/else` statement.

Let's say we are constructing a heap by giving maximum heap size in primitive java int type.
And this is my constructor.

```
public Heap(int maximumSize) {
        this.maximumSize = maximumSize;
        if (maximumSize < 1) {
            this.maximumSize = 100;
        }
        data = new int[this.maximumSize];
}
```

And i can write this also as

```
public Heap(int maximumSize) {
        if (maximumSize < 1) {
            this.maximumSize = 100;
        } else {
            this.maximumSize = maximumSize;
        }    
        data = new int[this.maximumSize];
}
```

I am wondering which is more efficient way considering all low level processes?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  This kind of micro-optimization means nothing.  Write the one that's most readable; that's subjective.  I vote for #1.  I'd worry more about the fact that you allow maximumSize to be negative or zero.  Does that make sense?  Check your precondition.

Comment: Use a tool to show the bytecode (low-level instructions) generated for each code, and search for the actual cost of those instructions.

Comment: @Mephy could you tell me name of that tool?

Comment: Decent chances are, the compiler is going to produce the same code for both fragments.

Comment: Personally, I would vote for `if(maximumSize < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The size must be greater than 0"); this.maximumSize = maximumSize;`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I highly doubt that the same code will be generated by the compiler as the two snippets are not logically equivalent. The difference is completely trivial, however.

Comment: @duffymo sorry, i forgot a line of code there. Just fixed it.

Comment: Did you try running your code with `maximumSize` parameter of, say, `-1`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, in both example, if given maximumSize parameter is less than 1, it will just assign 100 to maximumSize int instance.

Comment: The tool ships with the JDK; it's called javap.exe

Comment: @beli Now it does, but before the edit it threw `NegativeArraySizeException` :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry, i forgot to write `this` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like [premature optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). In the first instance, we should worry about correctness and readability, and focus on performance only when there's direct evidence -- usually obtained through profiling -- that the code in question is a performance bottleneck.

With this in mind, I would write

```
public Heap() {
    this(100);
}

public Heap(int maximumSize) {
    if (maximumSize < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            String.format("invalid maximumSize: %d", maximumSize));
    }
    this.maximumSize = maximumSize;
    data = new int[this.maximumSize];
}
```

The idea behind having two separate constructors is to eliminate the unintuitive "use a default when maximumSize is zero" behaviour. The two constructors make the default vs non-default behavoiur explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very *hip* these days, but you could collapse it all down using the ternary operator

```
this.maximumSize = maximumSize < 1 ? 100 : maximumSize;
```

Comment: This is certainly true but does not actually answer the question, which requested a performance analysis of the two snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of micro level method two is the better approach because method one follow the following steps :
1) create a variable maximumsize with default value.
2) initialize the variable with passed parameter.
3) check for the condition.
4) if true reinitialize it.
 At the same time step two follows following step:
1)create a variable maximumsize with default value.
2) check for the consition .
3) initialize maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

First Method Class :

```
public class Heap {

        private int maximumSize;

        public Heap(int maximumSize) {
            this.maximumSize = maximumSize;
            if (maximumSize < 1) {
                this.maximumSize = 100;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Heap heap = new Heap(10);
        }

}
```

compiled and get the byte code as,

```
rakesh@Rakesh-KR:/media/rakesh/WorkZ$ javap -c Heap
Compiled from "Heap.java"
public class Heap {
  public Heap(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: iload_1       
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field maximumSize:I
       9: iload_1       
      10: iconst_1      
      11: if_icmpge     20
      14: aload_0       
      15: bipush        100
      17: putfield      #2                  // Field maximumSize:I
      20: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #3                  // class Heap
       3: dup           
       4: bipush        10
       6: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":(I)V
       9: astore_1      
      10: return        
}
```

And for the second method;

```
if (maximumSize < 1) {
      this.maximumSize = 100;
 } else {
      this.maximumSize = maximumSize;
 }
```

the byte code as,

```
rakesh@Rakesh-KR:/media/rakesh/WorkZ$ javap -c Heap
Compiled from "Heap.java"
public class Heap {
  public Heap(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: iload_1       
       5: iconst_1      
       6: if_icmpge     18
       9: aload_0       
      10: bipush        100
      12: putfield      #2                  // Field maximumSize:I
      15: goto          23
      18: aload_0       
      19: iload_1       
      20: putfield      #2                  // Field maximumSize:I
      23: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #3                  // class Heap
       3: dup           
       4: bipush        10
       6: invokespecial #4                  // Method "<init>":(I)V
       9: astore_1      
      10: return        
}
```

I shared this as not as an answer. By reading the byte code any one can edit this answer to. I added a point here.

1. In first method the full process completed in 20 step. But in second
   it takes 23 steps.